# Loading a Power BI Embedded report by jquery.load( )

Tags: jquery, powerbi

I'm afraid this question will be very niche (since Power BI Embedded is a brand new feature in Azure which is still under preview mode).

So here goes:

When I render a Power BI report via an MVC View/PartialView, it works (the report is rendered on the DOM and I can see the interactive report.

But when I call the MVC View/PartialView by invoking it from jquery, then it does NOT render (although I see the Div element with various attributes that the Power BI Embedded API does behind the scenes).

The jquery call looks something like this:

```
$('#content').load('Report', 'Home');
```

Comment: The Power BI community forums may have more expertise than here.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript in the Report view?

Comment: Just curious, why you have to do this?

Comment: @JohnKurlak, there is no javascript in the report view (other than anything emitted by the Power BI Embedded report itself).

Comment: @CuongLe, I don't HAVE to do it. I just want to do it just because I would like to see it working :)

Comment: MVC nuget is just a wrapper, it uses iframe under the hood, take a look powerbi.js, the main line is: `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(initEventArgs.message), '*');`